# Incoming call notification like whats app when we are in another app

Tags: android

Once we received the FCM push notification message in android 10 background start activities were restricted. I need to implement incoming calls in my application if the app is in the background a calling notification should be triggered like WhatsApp or telegram, how do I achieve this.

Comment: You can achieve it using a broadcast reciever.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.